# How to show current date in detailview asp.net automatically

Tags: asp.net

I'm using asp.net and I'm creating a detail view from a database. The database I create got a column I want set auto show current when edit or insert like using timer like vb.net code

```
lblClock.Text = TimeOfDay
```

My Sample source from asp.net :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time Out" SortExpression="TIME_OUT">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TIME_OUT") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TIME_OUT") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TIME_OUT") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

What I want is when I click the edit button it will automatically show the current time and then I just click update.

Answer (score 0):

try this..........`TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");`

Answer (score 0):

In your Page Load event add this code

```
lblClock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```